# Enable an input textbox then focus it - jQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have an input textbox which is initially disabled.

```
<input type="text" name="count" id="count" value="0" disabled="true" data-theme="b" />
```

When I check a radio button i want to enable and focus the textbox, but when i click the radio button it enables the textbox and focuses some other textbox. I think it does not work because the textbox was initially disabled and you can not focus a disabled input.

```
$(":input[@name='radio']").live('change', function() { 
  $(":input[@name='count']").removeAttr("disabled").focus();
});
```

How do I enable the textbox and then focus it?

Comment: $(":input[@name='count']").removeAttr("disabled"); $(":input[@name='count']").focus();

Comment: First remove disabled attr than focus it. like $(":input[@name='count']").removeAttr("disabled")
$(":input[@name='radio']").focus();

Comment: nope ... it does not work ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears it was something wrong with the selector ... although the text input box got enabled, it did not get focused, while I tried:

```
$(":input[@name='count']").removeAttr("disabled").focus();
```

But when i tried this, it worked:

```
$("#count").removeAttr("disabled").focus();
```

I can not explain why this is happening ...

---

**Edit:**
It has something to the with the selector, because this works too:

```
$("input[name='count']").removeAttr("disabled").focus();
```

but i still can't understand why using the first selector, the textbox gets enabled, but not focused ...

Comment: If you are using jquery-mobile, my guess would be that the page has more than one input named count (which is easy to miss using jqMobile, as typically your ENTIRE site is "on the page" and jqMobile is handling the sexy animations to just flip between elements on the same page). It would seem that your id was more unique (that, or jQuery knows not to return multiple results for an id lookup), and thus that worked out for you :)

Comment: nope ... that isn't the problem ... the name of my text input is unique, i just called it "count" here to simplify the problem ... that "some other textbox" that i said gets focused has a different name and it always is the last input textbox on the page ...

Answer (score 1):

Try below code

```
$('#count').textinput('enable').focus();
```

Comment: I already tried, but i get this error in the firebug console: "uncaught exception: cannot call methods on textinput prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'enable'" ... other suggestions?

Comment: Use javascript document.getElementById("count").focus();.I have already used above jquery mobile code and its work fine in all browsers.

Comment: nice answer it solved my problem, which is from more then 3 hours ... good solution for jquery mobile

Answer (score 0):

It working fine for me

see

http://jsfiddle.net/kunalvashist/LFXd2/

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it on pageshow.

```
  $("#mainPage").on("pageshow", function (e) {
    $('#searchField').focus();
});
```

on

```
<body class="ui-mobile-viewport ui-overlay-c">
    <div data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true" id="mainPage">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme='b'>
           <input type="text" id="searchField" placeholder="Search" />
        </div>
    </div>
</body
```